# How to multiply matrices with a nested loop (python)

Tags: matrix, nested-loops, matrix-multiplication

I have one matrix, lets call it A, which is [6482x1]. I have another matrix, lets call it B, which is [6482x1827]. I want to create a new matrix, C, which multiplies every value in row i in matrix B with the value in row I for matrix A. How do i do this?

EG if A= [X, Y, Z] and B = [1 2 3, 4 5 6, 7 8 9]

I would like C to be [1X 2X 3X, 4Y 5Y 6Y, 7Z, 8Z, 9Z]

UPDATE

I have written this, but cannot understand what is not working about this:

[image]

Comment: `j` is supposed to be a column index and `k` is supposed to be a row index but you're using them backwards in `b[j][k]`.

Comment: ahh so simply writing result[i][j]=a[i]*b[k][j] should work?

Comment: No, that's just why you're getting the indexerror. You're also replacing the value of `result[i][j]` on every iteration of `for k ...`.

Comment: Oh right, thank you. Do you know how I can get the code to work?

Comment: Could it work with for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(b[0])):
            result[i,j]=a[i]*b[i][j]

Comment: Replace the entire thing with `a[:, None] * b` and stop screwing around with loops